# Angular CLI custom webpack config

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-loader

In previous versions of Angular there was an option for [eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/1-x-eject) so that you could modify your webpack configuration as you please.
One of the most common use cases for this feature was adding custom webpack loaders.

In Angular 6 this option has been removed, so currently there is literally no way to get the webpack config (beside looking it up in angular source code).

Is there any way to add a custom webpack config to Angular application that uses @angular/cli 6+?  Or alternatively, is there any way to "eject" the webpack config the new Angular CLI uses under the hood?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use [angular-builders](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders) library that allows you extending the existing `browser` and `server` targets (and more than that) with a custom webpack config.

The usage is pretty simple:

1. Install the library: `npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack`
2. Modify your *angular.json*:

   ```
   "architect": {
      ...
      "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
                 "customWebpackConfig": {
                    "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
                    "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
                 },
                 "outputPath": "dist/my-cool-library",
                 "index": "src/index.html",
                 "main": "src/main.ts",
                 "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                 "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
                 ...
          }
   ```
3. Add *extra-webpack.config.js* to the root of your application
4. Put the extra configuration inside *extra-webpack.config.js* (just a plain webpack configuration)

- [Quick guide](https://www.justjeb.com/post/customizing-angular-cli-build)
- [Full documentation](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack)
- [An example](https://github.com/just-jeb/electron-angular-native) that adds `node-loader` to browser config.

Comment: I can't get this working in my project. It doesn't load the extra-webpack.config.js at all. I installed all dependencies following the instructions. Any tips how to debug?

Comment: Please open an issue on github: https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/issues. Specify your _angular.json_, your _package.json_ and your _extra-webpack.config.js_.

Comment: Posted an issue https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/issues/19

Comment: I want to do this for test build, is it possible? Could you provide some instructions on this? All I need to do is attach a plugin.

Comment: Test builder for custom webpack not yet exists. You can open a feature request [here](https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/). You are also welcome to make a PR for this ;) How do you want to modify the test build?

Comment: @meltedspark Thanks, I was looking for something like the Angular CLI Builder, your answer pointed me to the right direction. My original question is here if you have any input:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896779/angular-cli-build-how-can-i-create-a-custom-index-file-generator-to-generate-an

Comment: Tried this but also having issues with cli 7.1.4. Schema validation failed with the following errors:Data path ".builders['browser']" should have required property 'class'.

Comment: I bet you've installed version 8 of the builders. You should use 7.

Comment: It's a good solution, but unfortunately I can't find any example about extending existing Angular CLI config file. I mean - I have to see what Angular CLI already generates for me, before I can think of correct overrides I should use in my builder override config. So, where do I find Angular's default generated webpack settings?

Comment: @JustAMartin https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs

Comment: @JeB Just curious: how is [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) different from [@angular-devkit/build-webpack](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_webpack)?

Are they both different solutions for the same problem, or do they solve two fundamentally different problems? Any comparisons between the two?

Comment: The latter. `build-webpack` just runs a webpack build (or webpack-dev-server) with a configuration you provide. No other functionality involved. Think of it as a way to run webpack build with Angular CLI. `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` on the other hand runs default Angular build chain while allowing to customize this build by providing a *delta* Webpack config that complements the default build configuration.

Comment: @JeB Hi, with the latest version of your library is it possible to specify a particular config in a webpack.config.js that exports multiple configurations or is another separate config file required?

Answer (score 9):

For Angular 8 `@angular-builders/dev-server:generic` has been deprecated and `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server` is being used instead, source: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/MIGRATION.MD.

On top of this you might need to run `npm i @angular-devkit/architect@latest @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest @angular-devkit/core@latest @angular-devkit/schematics@latest` if after migrating you would have seen the following error `architect_1.createBuilder is not a function`.