# How to run e2e test with ngx-build-plus (extra-webpack-config)?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-e2e, ngx-build-plus

I use *ngx-build-plus* to include a special webpack loader to integrate special custom files into our Angular-CLI build process (Angular 10).

Everything works fine, however I couldn't find a way to use e2e-tests this way, it's not even taking the `--extra-webpack-config` option...

```
$ ng e2e --extra-webpack-config webpack.partial.js
Unknown option: '--extra-webpack-config'
Unknown option: 'webpack.partial.js'
```

How could I fix the e2e tests to use the `webpack.partial.js` ?

Comment: the same issue mentioned on GitHub: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/issues/222

Comment: @Tony that was me in sync with this question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many things I've tried I couldn't find out how to get it to work with `ngx-build-plus` at all. However, I found out there is a different module `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` which provides exact the functionality of seamlessly extending an Angular-CLI webpack configuration and worked perfectly with my e2e-tests. There is no need to pass arguments to the build process, as the name of the webpack.conf fragment s configured in the `angular.json` config file:

```
"customWebpackConfig": {
    "path": "./webpack.config.js"
}
```

Comment: here's how to install the angular-builders: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130803/4255158

Answer (score -1):

Might be a little late here, but you need to change your builder in the `angular.json` file

Replace:

```
"builder": "angular-cli-builders:custom-webpack-browser"
```

With

```
"builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser"
```

This was not mentioned in the documentation so i had to do some [digging in their sample projects](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/blob/cli8/sample/angular.json). Works like a charm

[image: Successful Build]

Comment: The normal build was never a problem. The question is: How to get the e2e run to pass the correct options like the extra webpack config to the e2e build